# Adoconnection asks for userid and password when opened Delphi

Tags: delphi, ado, adoconnection

I am trying to open an ADOConnection component. The database is in MDB format. I use JET to access it.

Whenever I use AdoConnection.Open in my code the window pops up and asks for userid and pass. I enter "Admin" for userid and leave password empty, and it works, but I don't want this window to pop up. I tried using `AdoConnection.Open('Admin','');` but the window still pops up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the LoginPrompt on the connection object to FALSE

Answer (score 7):

Try:
`AdoConnection.LoginPrompt := False`